# Send email/notification to device A when receiving a call on a device B

Tags: logging, remote-control

I have a work phone, and I am not always able to answer the calls coming in.

I would like to set up a system where I receive a notification (email or otherwise) on my main device, even if I am away from my work device.

For example:

Notification on Device A:
Device B received a call from 555-2345 at 10:38AM.

Does anyone know of any apps that offer this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through IFTTT.

Look at [this recipe to send email notifications on missed calls](https://ifttt.com/applets/165574p-email-notification-for-missed-calls). You can find similar ones or create on your own, the learning curve isn't very high.